# Is there any way to create TouchEvents or something that works as one in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, touch-event

I'm trying to write a browser add-on that can create artificial `TouchEvents`. So far I have it working in Chrome but Firefox does not seem to support `TouchEvents`, as trying to create one with `new TouchEvent(...)` produces:

```
ReferenceError: TouchEvent is not defined
```

I'm wondering if there's some way I can either implement `TouchEvent` myself in the add-on or otherwise dispatch an event that has all the necessary properties to be usable like a `TouchEvent`.

However if I create a `CustomEvent` and assign it the extra properties necessary for it to effectively be a `TouchEvent` (i.e. `touches`, `targetTouches`, and `changedTouches`) those properties don't persist by the time the webpage receives the event.

Is there any way to accomplish what I'm after, or am I out of luck trying to get this to work in Firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else has this question, here is the solution I found. You can create your own class that extends UIEvent like so:

```
class TouchEvent extends UIEvent {
    constructor(name, initDict) {
        super(name, initDict);
        this.touches = initDict.touches;
        this.targetTouches = initDict.targetTouches;
        this.changedTouches = initDict.changedTouches;
    }
}
```

The one caveat is that these events have to be constructed by a script running in the same domain as the handler that will receive them, otherwise you'll get a `Permission denied to access property` error. My solution for that was to use my extension's content script to add a script element in the current document's body and set its textContent property to my javascript code that creates and dispatches the touch events.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the accepted answer to work because I couldn't figure out how to construct the `touches` that need to be placed inside `initDict`. Here is what worked for me:

```js
function dispatchTouchEvent(eventName, details) {
    const uiEvent = document.createEvent('UIEvent');
    uiEvent.initUIEvent(eventName, true, true, window, 1);
    const event = Object.assign(uiEvent, {touches: [details]});
    details.target.dispatchEvent(event);
}
```

And here's how to invoke it with a `touchstart` event on the body element at coordinates (50, 100):

```js
dispatchTouchEvent('touchstart', {identifier: 0, target: document.body, pageX: 50, pageY: 100});
```

For my purposes I only needed to set the `pageX` and `pageY` properties, but depending on what you're doing it may be necessary to set `clientX`, `clientY`, `screenX`, or `screenY`.